# Filter rails record by 2 instances of child record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, filter

I'm trying to filter a list of Products based on 2 tags,

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base {
          :id => :integer,
  :created_at => :datetime,
  :updated_at => :datetime,
         :key => :string
}
```

How can I format a query statement that allows me to find a product which has 2 tags, one with key 'fragile', and one with key 'perishable'?

Comment: Do you only want if it has those two tags? or even with one tag

Comment: only if it has both tags

Comment: Are you using postgresql?

Comment: yes, using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.joins(:tags).where("tags.key IN (?)", ['fragile', 'perishable']).group('products.id').having('COUNT(tags.id) = ?', 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works with counting products.id as well.

Comment: A more idiomatic way of the `WHERE...IN` clause would be:
```ruby
.where(tags: { key: ['fragile', 'perishable'] })
```